# Upgrading a Azure function app to 3.0.0-beta8 and having som DI code break after

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

[image]

before i updated the dlls Config is off type JobHostConfiguration, any suggestion how to work around this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by implementing the DI code like in this repo

https://github.com/ryanspletzer/DependencyInjectionAzureFunction

Answer (score 3):

I have created a nuget package for my solution which fixes the issue and also has the ability to use any IoC container: https://github.com/BorisWilhelms/azure-function-dependency-injection