# What is the replacement for Microsoft.Azure.WebHosts.JobHostConfiguration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Trying to follow [@matthoneycutt](https://twitter.com/matthoneycutt) 's [tutorial on Azure IoT Hub](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/azure-iot-hub-developers-getting-started/table-of-contents) it seems like 
Microsoft.Azure.WebHosts.JobHostConfiguration vanished between 3.0.0-beta5
and 3.0.0-rc1 releases of  Microsoft.Azure.WebHosts.Host in the Microsoft.Azure.WebHosts nuget package?

What would be the approach to get this code up running in Microsoft.Azure.WebHosts 3.0.0-rc1?

```
var processorHost = new EventProcessorHost(hubName, consumerGroupName, iotHubConnectionString, storageConnectionString,storageContainerName);
processorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<LoggingEventProcessor>().Wait();
var eventHubConfig = new EventHubConfiguration();
eventHubConfig.AddEventProcessorHost(hubName, processorHost);
var configuration = new JobHostConfiguration(storageConnectionString);
configuration.UseEventHub(eventHubConfig);
var host = new JobHost(configuration);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

Seems related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150861/upgrading-a-azure-function-app-to-3-0-0-beta8-and-having-som-di-code-break-after), though in a different context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that thru the AddEventHubs extension methods (available in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs package)

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                .AddAzureStorage()
                .AddEventHubs(eventHubOptions => {
                    var hubName = "hubName";
                    var iotHubConnectionString = "iotHubConnectionString";
                    var storageContainerName = "storageContainerName";
                    var storageConnectionString = "storageConnectionString";
                    var consumerGroupName = "consumerGroupName";

                    var processorHost = new EventProcessorHost(hubName, consumerGroupName, iotHubConnectionString, storageConnectionString, storageContainerName);
                    eventHubOptions.AddEventProcessorHost("eventHubName", processorHost);
                })
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about your configuration please? Are you using v3.0.0 or a pre-release? I cannot see `AddAzureStorageCoreServices` when I try this.

Comment: Nevermind; I was able to get it working by uninstalling and reinstalling Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0.

Comment: @Aaron I would like to mark this as the answer if I can confirm it works, but I can't locate IWebJobsBuilder.AddAzureStorageCoreServices in the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0 nuget package. Could you specify uninstalling / reinstalling Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs?

Comment: @noontz You need to add the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage nuget package @ https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage

Comment: @JulienJacobs Sorry for the late reply. I still have the same issue as before regarding AddAzureStorageCoreServices() not being available on IWebJobsBuilder. Currently on Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.1

Comment: @noontz maybe try to also add package "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions"

Comment: @JulienJacobs Thanks..That solved it.. Consider updating your answer with the required packages ;)